# PHPmailer smtp to exchange - "DATA END command failed" after 30s (but no timeout)

Tags: php, smtp, exchange-server, phpmailer, exchange-server-2016

I am using the latest PHPMailer 5.2.24 (problem is the same with older versions) on PHP 7.0.

Sending mails via SMTP with an Exchange 2016. About 95% of the mails work like expected, but whenever the 250 response from Exchange to the final DATA END command lasts longer than 30sec the stream seems to abort.

Timeout in PHPMailer is set to 300 and in the logs i can confirm that timeout is not the Problem here.

In fact all the Mails are sucessfully send as far as i can tell (i confirmed it in about 30 of 30 cases).

```
$this->mailer->isSMTP();
$this->mailer->Timeout = 300;
$this->mailer->Host = 'mail.myhost.com';
$this->mailer->SMTPAuth = true;
$this->mailer->Username = 'Domain\\Username';
$this->mailer->Password = '*****';
$this->mailer->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$this->mailer->Port = 587;
```

Low level log example: (i added 2 custom debug outputs inside get_lines() of class.smtp.php to show that fgets() returns false and to show the stream_get_meta_data())

```
2017-08-23 13:46:05 Level 1; message: CLIENT -> SERVER: .

2017-08-23 13:46:35 Level 4; message: SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is ""
2017-08-23 13:46:35 Level 4; message: SMTP -> get_lines(): $str === false 
2017-08-23 13:46:35 Level 4; message: SMTP -> [timed_out => false, blocked => 1, eof => 1, stream_type => tcp_socket/ssl, mode => r+, unread_bytes => 0, seekable => false]
2017-08-23 13:46:35 Level 2; message: SERVER -> CLIENT: 
2017-08-23 13:46:35 Level 1; message: SMTP ERROR: DATA END command failed:
```

In the other cases with response faster than 30s it would look like:

```
2017-08-23 23:25:02 Level 1; message: CLIENT -> SERVER: .
2017-08-23 23:25:28 Level 4; message: SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is ""
2017-08-23 23:25:28 Level 4; message: SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is  "250 2.6.0 <...> [InternalId=10677288697896, Hostname=myhost] 32443 bytes in 26.353, 1,202 KB/sec Queued mail for delivery"
2017-08-23 23:25:28 Level 2; message: SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 2.6.0 <...> [InternalId=10677288697896, Hostname=myhost] 32443 bytes in 26.353, 1,202 KB/sec Queued mail for delivery
2017-08-23 23:25:28 Level 1; message: CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
```

So what could

```
$str = fgets($this->smtp_conn, 515);
```

cause to fail after exactly 30sec (30sec after its execution, not since script start) when it is not a timeout of the stream and not a php runtime timeout. (No Exception is thrown here, i removed the @ from fgets() in the original PHPMailer code to confirm this)

Script is running without max_execution_time.

My Exchange administrator has no idea what could cause this and i dont have a point to begin with as i dont even know where the stream breaks - PHP, Webserver, Exchange, somwhere between?

Any Ideas what else i could check or what could cause this?

Comment: This is probably a sort-of bug in PHP. See https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/issues/604

Comment: My problem is more like the opposite of the linked bug - my problem is not that timeout is not working (it is working, i tested with a lower timeout so that it ran in timeout before the 30sec limit). My problem is that the stream somehow breaks after 30sec and does not stay open till the 300sec timeout.

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess that it's the [`max_execution_time`](http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time) of your PHP installation, which defaults to 30 sec, and it happens to always fail here because that's the only thing in your code that takes that long.

Try increasing it in your php.ini or calling [`set_time_limit()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) beforehand.

Comment: As i said it is not the execution time. My script is finishing just fine after that point - btw its running by crontab without execution_time limit. And fgets() is failing after exactly 30sec - the whole script may be already running 31 or more seconds at this time.

Comment: OK - try this, see if it matches anything interesting: `php -i | grep 30`.

Comment: Nothing  - besides the mysqli.default port of 3306 :)

Comment: Oh what i forgot to mention - all mails (as far as i can tell) are send sucessfully, PHPMailer just "thinks" thats not the case as the stream ends before 250 confirmation.

Comment: I'd suspect something in the environment or server since PHPMailer is only acting on the information it's given. Perhaps inspect the traffic with wireshark to see what's going on at a lower level?

Comment: ok i was afraid of something like that - hoped i had missed something more easy. thx